# How to return to previous line of code after Ctrl+Click in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

How to return to previous line of code after being moved by <kbd>Ctrl+Click</kbd> in PhpStorm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In main menu look at **"Navigate | Back"** action and use that shortcut (as it will be different depending on your OS and Keymap used).

On Windows with Default keymap it will be <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + Left</kbd>